# Solving linear system of equations containing matrices and vectors

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, linear-equation

I want to solve the following linear system of equations in Python:

[image]

with

**`A`** is a matrix of size `3 x 3`

**`b`** is a vector of ones of length `3`

**`b'`** stands for the transpose of b

**`c`** is a vector of zeros of length `3`

**`d`** is a vector of length `3`

**My Python code is as follows:**

```
A = np.array(([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3])) 
b = np.ones(3)
c = np.zeros(3)
d = np.array([4,5,6]) 

matrix1 = np.array(([A,b], [b.T, c]))
matrix2 = np.array([d, b])
        
[alpha, beta] = np.linalg.solve(matrix1, matrix2)
```

I am obtaining the error `for matrix 1`: `could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3)`.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Seems like the stacking of array is wrong.

Comment: The shapes of the arrays `A`, `b`, `b'`, and `c` are not compatible to create a single matrix of coefficients. If `b` has a single row, then it cannot be horizontally stacked with `A` which has 3 rows. If, on the other hand, `b` is supposed to have 3 rows and 1 column, then `c` would have to be a 1x1 matrix, and `d` would have to be a single number too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [2]: A = np.array(([1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]))
   ...: b = np.ones(3)
   ...: c = np.zeros(3)
   ...: d = np.array([4,5,6])
```

Look at `b` and `b.T`.  See any difference?  A (3,) shape has been changed to (3,) shape.  Surprised?  Then you haven't taken time to read the `np.transpose` docs.

```
In [3]: b
Out[3]: array([1., 1., 1.])
In [4]: b.T
Out[4]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

So lets try to make your array:

```
In [5]: np.array(([A,b], [b.T, c]))
<ipython-input-5-45ec84398f1d>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array(([A,b], [b.T, c]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-45ec84398f1d>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array(([A,b], [b.T, c]))
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3,)
```

Or how about just the first part:

```
In [6]: np.array([A,b])
<ipython-input-6-dff0caaab877>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array([A,b])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-6-dff0caaab877>", line 1, in <module>
    np.array([A,b])
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,3) into shape (3,)
```

Sometimes `np.array(...)` with inconsistent shaped inputs produces an object dtype array; other times, such as this, it raises an error.

The basic point is, we can't make a new array by simply combining a (3,3) and (3,).

We could make `b` into a (3,1) shape, and concatenate that with `A`:

```
In [8]: b[:,None]
Out[8]: 
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])
In [9]: np.hstack((A,b[:,None]))
Out[9]: 
array([[1., 2., 3., 1.],
       [1., 2., 3., 1.],
       [1., 2., 3., 1.]])
```

We could try the same with the 2nd row

```
In [11]: np.hstack((b,c))
Out[11]: array([1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.])
```

but this joins a (3,) and (3,) to make a (6,)  (surprised?  Do the math! ).  But joining a (3,) with (1,) produces a (4,)

```
In [12]: np.hstack((b,[0]))
Out[12]: array([1., 1., 1., 0.])
```

That in turn can be joined to the (3,4) to produce a (4,4):

```
In [14]: np.vstack((np.hstack((A,b[:,None])), np.hstack((b,[0]))))
Out[14]: 
array([[1., 2., 3., 1.],
       [1., 2., 3., 1.],
       [1., 2., 3., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

There may be more streamlined ways of constructing this array, but I'm going through all the details because you don't have much a understanding yet of `numpy` array dimensions.

Don't casually import terms like `matrix` and `vector` into `numpy`.  `numpy` has arrays, which may be 1d, 2d or more (even 0d).  They aren't exactly like school book linear algebra objects.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. I will check it when I come back home this evening. Do you tested also the linalg.solve ? Does it also work fine?